# How to download videos from Procam xr2 in Ubuntu?

Tags: usb, camera

Can anybody help me downloading my videos from a procam camera?

It is listed in **lsusb** this way:

```
 Polaroid Corp a500 Digital Camera
```

**dmesg** shows this:

```
[13135.304931] usb 2-1.1: new high-speed USB device number 10 using ehci_hcd
[13135.399598] scsi13 : usb-storage 2-1.1:1.0
[13136.507543] scsi 13:0:0:0: Direct-Access     Digital  Camera Storage   1.00 PQ: 0 ANSI: 5
[13136.508257] sd 13:0:0:0: Attached scsi generic sg2 type 0
[13136.509449] sd 13:0:0:0: [sdc] 15661056 512-byte logical blocks: (8.01 GB/7.46 GiB)
[13136.509811] sd 13:0:0:0: [sdc] Write Protect is off
[13136.509815] sd 13:0:0:0: [sdc] Mode Sense: 17 00 00 08
[13136.510183] sd 13:0:0:0: [sdc] No Caching mode page present
[13136.510186] sd 13:0:0:0: [sdc] Assuming drive cache: write through
[13136.512459] sd 13:0:0:0: [sdc] No Caching mode page present
[13136.512464] sd 13:0:0:0: [sdc] Assuming drive cache: write through
[13136.514075]  sdc: sdc1
[13136.516448] sd 13:0:0:0: [sdc] No Caching mode page present
[13136.516452] sd 13:0:0:0: [sdc] Assuming drive cache: write through
[13136.516456] sd 13:0:0:0: [sdc] Attached SCSI removable disk
[13136.535664] sd 13:0:0:0: [sdc] Unhandled sense code
[13136.535668] sd 13:0:0:0: [sdc]  Result: hostbyte=invalid driverbyte=DRIVER_SENSE
[13136.535672] sd 13:0:0:0: [sdc]  Sense Key : Medium Error [current] 
[13136.535677] sd 13:0:0:0: [sdc]  Add. Sense: Unrecovered read error
[13136.535682] sd 13:0:0:0: [sdc] CDB: Read(10): 28 00 00 ee f7 f0 00 00 08 00
[13136.535692] end_request: critical target error, dev sdc, sector 15661040
[13136.535695] quiet_error: 293 callbacks suppressed
[13136.535698] Buffer I/O error on device sdc, logical block 1957630
```

Tried googling it, but with no luck.

Can someone help?

Answer (score 1):

Your camera seems to identify itself as a USB mass storage device. Usually that means that you can just plug it in and it will behave as an USB pendrive.

However checking your dmesg shows that the USB implementation of it is broken. It does not fully conform to the standard. This means there are two ways to get this camera working:

1. Kick the manufacturer until he produces something which works correctly.
   (Read, until enough people complain and he release a firmware update).
2. Work around the bugs by adding the problems to the USB quirks list.

You can do this by editing `linux/drivers/usb/core/quirks.c` and recompiling the kernel.

See also:
 - https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/linux/+bug/913567
 - http://lxr.free-electrons.com/source/drivers/usb/core/quirks.c